# Let T be a linear operator on a vector space V over F. Prove that $Ker~ T\subset Ker~ T^2$ and $Im~ T^2\subset Im~ T$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let T be a linear operator on a vector space V over F. Prove that $Ker~ T\subset Ker~ T^2$ and $Im~ T^2\subset Im~ T$

I know the definition of $Ker~ T$ & $Im~ T$. Using those, I am unable to solve the problem. Please help with elementary properties of Linear Transformation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $v\in ker(T)$ we have $T(v)=0$ and so espacially $T^2(v)=T(T(v))=T(0)=0$ and therefore $v\in ker(T^2)$.

For $v\in im(T^2)$ we have a $w\in V$ with $T^2(w)=v$ and so especially $T(T(w))=v$ which means $v$ is the image of $T(w)$ and so $v\in im(T)$.